# Adding default font features to \sffamily

Tags: fontspec

It seems I can't add any extra default font features with `fontspec` after the font is set e.g. with `\setsansfont`.  Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fontspec,xcolor}

%% <Part set by myfira.sty>
\defaultfontfeatures[MyFira]{%
  Extension      = .otf                   ,
  UprightFont    = FiraSans-Regular       ,
  ItalicFont     = FiraSans-RegularItalic ,
  BoldFont       = FiraSans-SemiBold      ,
  BoldItalicFont = FiraSans-SemiBoldItalic
}
\setsansfont{MyFira}
%% </Part set by myfira.sty>

%% <Part set by user after \usepackage{myfira.sty}>
\defaultfontfeatures+[\sffamily]{Scale=.75, Color=red}
%% </Part set by user after \usepackage{myfira.sty}>

\begin{document}

{\fontspec{MyFira}\addfontfeatures{Scale=.75, Color=blue}\lipsum[1]}% works
{\sffamily % does not work
  \defaultfontfeatures+[MyFira]{Scale=.75, Color=red}\lipsum[1]}
\sffamily % does not work
  \defaultfontfeatures+[\sffamily]{Scale=.75, Color=red}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Use case is to have a package which defines `MyFira` and users can load this package and add further features with `\defaultfontfeatures+`.  I could delay `\setsansfont{MyFira}` with `\AtBeginDocument` but it doesn't help if a user wants to change something in the middle of the document.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The key here is 'default': you are declaring what the defaults are for a specific font (or font family) and then declaring that font via `\set...font`. It is not meant to create 'new defaults' for previously declared fonts. If you want to use `\defaultfontfeature` mid-document, I think you need to reset also with `\setsansfont`.  It would probably be better to define a `\newfontfamily`, which I suppose you could `\let` to `\sffamily`. The priority order of feature selection in `fontspec` is: `\addfontfeatures` trumps `\fontspec`, which trumps `\defaultfontfeatures`.

Comment: As @jon says, as I understand it, this is simply by design i.e. this is just how these things are meant to work. Why can't users use `\addfontfeatures` after the document starts? The features obviously aren't intended to be defaults at that point. And you can delay until after the preamble to catch their custom defaults.

Comment: @jon - Thanks for your comment.  My understanding of the docs was that `\defaultfontfeature+` (with **+**) _does_ create new defaults for previously declared fonts.  It seems I've got it wrong.  Your suggestion with reset `\setsansfont` did the trick.  If you want to turn that comment into an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks.  I think setting the defaults with `\defaultfontfeature+` in preamble is more clear than setting things after document start.